How ot create a generic on UPDATE trigger in Oracle 12c
I am trying to create a generic on UPDATE trigger for a table named EMPLOYEES. Table has EMP_ID as PK and several columns (by the term generic I mean that I will not have to hard code and check every table's column one by one).
In the case of an UPDATE, I want to store the old value in a second table named EMPLOYEES_AUDITING with the following structure (EMPLOYEES_PK, ACTION_DT, UPDATED_FIELD, UPDATED_VALUE);
In order to check which columns were updated each time, I am suing the IF UPDATING condition.
This is my approach so far
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER UPDATE_MONITOR 
BEFORE UPDATE ON EMPLOYEES

FOR EACH ROW
  
DECLARE  
SELECT column_name FROM dba_tab_columns WHERE table_name = 'EMPLOYEES';

v_name VARCHAR2 (100);

BEGIN

   OPEN coi;
   LOOP
     FETCH coi INTO v_name;
     EXIT WHEN coi% NOTFOUND;

     IF UPDATING(v_name) THEN 

       -- Insert old value in the EMPLOYEES_AUDITING table
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
        'INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES_AUDITING (EMPLOYEES_PK, ACTION_DT, UPDATED_FIELD, UPDATED_VALUE)
 VALUES (:OLD.EMP_ID, SYSDATE, '||v_name||', :OLD.'||v_name||')';

     END IF;
   END LOOP;
   
   CLOSE coi;

END;


The problem is the :NEW.'||v_name||' part fails to 'translate' into the proper column name's OLD value. Any ideas or workarounds?
Thank you in advance

Read through the answer by APC in the question I referenced above. Alternatively, you could use generate audit triggers using Connor McDonalds' code described here. Bottom line... don't try to reinvent the wheel.
